# Use a span tag to change div background-color onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following html code:

```
    <div id="parent" style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
     <ul>    
      <li><span data-color="red">Text 1</span></li>
      <li><span data-color="blue">Text 2</span></li>
      <li><span data-color="yellow">Text 3</span></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

If I click on specific `<span>`, the div parent's background color should be changed.

How this can be done using jQuery?

I've tried this:

```
$('ul li span').click(function(){
   $('.parent').css('background-color', $(this).data-color);
});
```

Comment: where is your js code and what issues you are facing? SO is not a code writing service, you need to try something yourself first

Comment: I dont have any yet, I'm very new to jquery

Comment: Thats very rude of you guys thinking I want the code... I want tips like "you should try tu use classes or data-color in the span to do this and this" not the code...

Comment: @RafaelMoraisdosSantos this site is for people who have tried something and need help. There are too many good tutorials out there that could teach you this. Members of this site are to assume to be "professionals", however all we want is a simple attempt from those that ask, no matter their skill level. Just try, and we can't badger you for giving a good effort.

Comment: Ok, I will try and do something

Comment: Good man! We look forward to your attempt! (also, for "easy" questions, feel free to ask the chat. No worry of downvotes there, but some of them can be impatient to people who don't listen lol)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the chat. I've already submitted my attempt

Comment: @RafaelMoraisdosSantos mistakes in your code you are using class selector instead of id selector. and $(this).data-color has to change to $(this).data('color') check my answer or fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k6t80zsg/2/

Comment: Thanks everyone who helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using vanilla JavaScript (no libraries):

```
//We attach a click handler on the nearest common parent.
//This allows us to have only one event handler, which is better
//For performance!
document.getElementById("parent").onclick = function(e) {
    //We only want events on the spans, so let's check that!
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "span") { 
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#BADA55";
        //This is for the sake of example only!
        //TODO: A better approach would be to add a class
        //And define a CSS rule for that class.
    }
};
```

Or without the comments

```
document.getElementById("parent").onclick = function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagname.toLowerCase() == "span") { 
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#BADA55";
    }
};
```

The equivalent of the above with jQuery:

```
$("#parent").on("span", "click", function() {
    $("#parent").css({backgroundColor: "#BADA55"});
});
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fx1oL71w/1/)**

Answer (score -3):

```
$('ul li span').on('click',function(){
     $(this).closest('div').css('background-color',$(this).data('color'));
})

<div id="parent" style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
 <ul>    
  <li><span data-color='red'>Text 1</span></li>
  <li><span data-color='yellow'>Text 2</span></li>
  <li><span data-color='green'>Text 3</span></li>
 </ul>
```

here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/k6t80zsg/3/

Comment: i want to show him the usage of closest method. we can use directly change color by using id. but if he has multiple elements with same structure i prefer closest method thats why given example

Comment: your comment was helpfull, thanks